# Need to Apply pipe for specific property out of many property

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am receiving 18 property from API, I need to apply date pipe for a two-property value. How I can apply in `.ts` file out of 18 property.

In below the code,

```
return {
       prop: i,
       index: index,                     
       };
```

give all the property. and return to _cols, I need to apply date pipe for two fields to make the date as US format.

this is `.ts` file:

```
private getStatusSummary(clearCache?: boolean) {
this.loaderService.startLoader(this.loader.id);
let params = {
  reportname: 'getscriptstatusdisplay',
  fromDate: '',
  toDate: ''
};
params = merge({}, params, this.filters);

this.httpClient
  .cache(clearCache)
  .get(`/${API.sourceStatusSummary}`, {
    params: params
  })
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      this.loaderService.stopLoader(this.loader.id);
      const error = get(data, 'errorMessage', '');
      const records = get(data, 'body', []);
      if (error) {
      } else {
        this.rows = records;
        let _cols =
          isArray(this.rows) && this.rows.length > 0
            ? Object.keys(get(this.rows, '[0]')).map((i, index) => 
          {
                  return {
                  prop: i,
                  index: index,                     
                };

              })
            : [];
        this.tempRows = records;

        this.columns = _cols;     

        this.allColumns = _cols;
        this.columns.push({
          prop: 'Action',
          index: this.columns.length,
          width: 100,
          resizeable: false,
          sortable: false,
          cellTemplate: this.actionTemplate
        });

        this.setError('');
      }
    },
    error => {
      this.loaderService.stopLoader(this.loader.id);
      this.setError(error);
    }
  );
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
   <ngx-datatable
    [rows]="rows"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [scrollbarH]="true"
    class="bootstrap"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [reorderable]="'false'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [limit]="ITEM_PER_PAGE"
    [hidden]="rows.length === 0"  

  #table
>
 <ngx-datatable-column
    [resizeable]="false"
    *ngFor="let col of columns;"
    [prop]="col.prop"
    [cellTemplate]="col.cellTemplate"
    [maxWidth]="col.maxWidth"
  >
  </ngx-datatable-column>
```

I need to display the date property as US(07-16-1997)formate as of now it is giving as  1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00

Answer (score 0):

should be easy, just pass the pipe you want to apply to that column's data:

[Ngx-Datatable Docs](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs)

Example: I want to format all the data in my column as currency values i.e instead 100000, it shows $100,000.

```
{
                prop: 'commitment',
                name: 'Hourly Commitment',
                pipe: this.currencyPipe
}
```

where I'm using the default currency pipe available in Angular. You can use the Date Pipe to solve your use-case. 
[Date Pipe from Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)